# Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\Fasih_khan\.gradle\caches\jars-8\d39c566f673fd9079bc7973003ab0a69\builder-4.2.2.jar

Tags: react-native, jar

npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 982 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'food_shop'.

> Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\Fasih_khan.gradle\caches\jars-8\d39c566f673fd9079bc7973003ab0a69\builder-4.2.2.jar.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'food_shop'.

> Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\Fasih_khan.gradle\caches\jars-8\d39c566f673fd9079bc7973003ab0a69\builder-4.2.2.jar.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s

```
at makeError (E:\COURSES\Development\Shop\food_shop\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)     
at E:\COURSES\Development\Shop\food_shop\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (E:\COURSES\Development\Shop\food_shop\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (E:\COURSES\Development\Shop\food_shop\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Answer (score 2):

For me error was like below
`GradleException: Failed to create Jar file /root/.gradle/caches/jars-8/da1fb602f5e9c4589f7a774fa11d9312/bin.jar`

Solution was : `touch /root/.gradle/caches/jars-8/da1fb602f5e9c4589f7a774fa11d9312/bin.jar`

If it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but with different jar - *spring-core-6.0.3.jar*.
It looks like gradle hold a lock on cached files for some reasons while building your *food_shop* application.
Correct solution is to figure out which daemon process made a lock, then stop it calling `gradle --stop` and then restart gradle build again.

If it's not helped then check your locked cache files:

1. `gradle --stop`
2. check if lib already exists, it may looks like `builder-4.2.2.jar.lock.lock`
3. delete it if so.
4. run `gradle build` again for your project.

If you have dozen processes of gradle wrapper and it's difficult to figure out which one locked the file this solution would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run yarn and then yarn android. In my case that's the only way I could make it work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).